# Mysterious battery drain

Tags: battery-life, nexus-5x

My battery has dropped more than the sum of the usage by all of my apps.

Has anyone ever experienced this before, or know where the rest of my battery is going?

[image: Battery usage]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Answer (score 2):

- Android depiction of battery consumption isn't very accurate- see [How does Android calculate battery consumption by apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/20451/131553) and I am not aware how much it has improved with the latest version. Having said that, the discrepancy in battery percentage as shown is *large* and it *could* be due

a)  **Inaccuracy of measurement**

b)  **Wakelocks** (see  tag [wakelock](/questions/tagged/wakelock) for more information)

- **Inaccurate measurement:** To verify this try installing an app like [GSam Battery Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gsamlabs.bbm&hl=en) which gives a more *granular* breakdown of battery consumption (I am not aware how it measures but in my experience is reliable). If your device is rooted , you could install the *helper* file of that app to get better results or use [BetterBatteryStats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats&hl=en), which by far is the best IMO (requires *Xposed Framework*- see tag [xposed-framework](/questions/tagged/xposed-framework) for more details )
- **Wakelocks:** can be a major culprit eating into your battery.  To start with, you could install [Wakelock Detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector)- suggesting this as first step since it works on both rooted and unrooted devices (see [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/41061/131553) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/146399/131553) for more details on installing/ using the app). Once you identify the culprit, following options are available:
- **System App (rooted devices only):**

  1. You could freeze or uninstall using apps like [Titanium backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) (there is always a risk of doing so, unless you are sure that it is *bloatware* and doesn't affect)
  2. Alternatively, limit the wakelocks without breaking functionality using [Amplify Battery Extender -Root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ryansteckler.nlpunbounce) (requires *Xposed Framework*)
- If your device is not rooted:

  a) If it is a system app, there isn't anything you can do

  b) If it is a user app, uninstall that app and look for alternate    apps     that don't drain the battery by wakelocks or use [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify)

  c) Contact the developer and hope that he fixes the wakelock problem

Answer (score 1):

First of all, find out the app which draining your battery from Blueren answer. And uninstall faulty app, but if you unable to find the app try these methods
1.)If you are trying any battery saver app than stop using that, because they cant stop any app to run in background. You can read [this article](http://www.techorfy.com/2016/04/do-memory-cleaner-apps-really-work-we.html), Revealing bitter truth of these apps

2.)Use Greenify instead, Greenify is one of the app which can stop any app to run in background. [[PLAYSTORE]](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en). Greenify work on Un-rooted device but with limited feature. If your device is rooted than you can use most of its feature. Check out this [Techorfy](http://www.techorfy.com/2016/04/6-proven-and-tried-tips-to-extend-battery-life.html) article for more.

3.) Try another battery, your device battery can be faulty. Head to Customer care centre if your Device has user not-removable battery.

4.) None of them working, than Flash a new Stock ROM. You need a [custom recovery, Stock ROM and a full detailed guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-5x/development/rom-nexus-5x-stock-rom-t3232701).

5.) 3G and 4G consume more battery specially if signal strength is low.

Answer (score 0):

This could be for a plathora of reasons ranging from signal strength to wakelocks. Simplest thing you could do is reboot your phone and see if it still drains out the way it is now.

More often than not, it usually could happen based on the wakelocks present. A badly designed app may very well be a culprit.

If you want to investigate further, you can try installing this app called Better Battery Stats that is available on the [play store](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi0_rWm5qvNAhUMOo8KHT9qDccQFggtMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.asksven.betterbatterystats%26hl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNFBmReBVjm_7kTEZNXpQwT4H8mDCQ&sig2=cIHKvGJ4RU-XTkcTL02TPA).

There is a dedicated thread relating to this app on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1179809)